# Storybook addon-knobs callback function knob

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a situation in Storybook [addon-knobs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-knobs) where I need a *knob* to change a callback function.

> I want `formatValue` to be a **knob** but I am unsure how (and if)
>   this can be done.

#### Here's the component's Story:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { withKnobs, boolean, text, number, object } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

import storybookWrapper from '../../storybook/StorybookWrapper';
import Slider from './Slider';

stories.addDecorator(withKnobs)
    .add('Slider', () => {
        const props = {
            name        : 'foo',
            value       : number('value', 200000),
            min         : number('min', 100),
            step        : number('step', 1000),
            max         : number('max', 1000000),
            // I want the below to be a knob:
            formatValue : v => '$ ' + Number(v).toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2})
        };

        const WrappedComponent = storybookWrapper(Slider, props);

        return <WrappedComponent />
    }
);
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

For now I "solved" it like this:
*(There is still no easy way to configure the `toLocaleString()` part)*

```
function formatValue(v) {
    return text('prefix', '$ ') + Number(v).toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2}) + text('suffix', '')
}

const props = {
     name        : 'loanRequest',
     value       : number('value', 200000),
     min         : number('min', 100),
     step        : number('step', 1000),
     max         : number('max', 1000000),
     formatValue
};
```

[image]